# Is there any way to run same grunt command in Mac and Windows but with different options or arguments?

Tags: cordova, gruntjs, cordova-cli

Lets say there is a grunt command build_release_android as shown below:

```
cordovacli: {
 .....

    build_release_android: {
                        options: {
                            command: 'build',
                            platforms: ['android'],
                            args: ['--release', "--buildConfig=..//build_android.json"]
                        }
                    }
.....
}
```

This command can be run in console as grunt cordovacli:build_release_android.

Now in Mac this works fine, but if run same command on Windows console, I have to change path as "--buildConfig=..\build_android.json"

So is there any way to run command without manually doing any change, everytime its run on different platforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `gruntfile.js`, you can check your environment's operating system and can use whichever arguments are appropriate. For example:

```js
var os = require('os');

...

cordovacli: {
    ...
    build_release_android: {
        options: {
            command: 'build',
            platforms: ['android'],
            args: /^win/.test(os.platform()) ?
                ['--release', '--buildConfig=..\\build_android.json'] :
                ['--release', '--buildConfig=../build_android.json']
        }
    }
    ...
}
```